# multiple definition of #define function

Tags: c++, c, g++

I have logger.h file and defining a macro function for logging:

```
//logger.h:
#ifndef _LOGGER_H_
#define _LOGGER_H_

#ifdef LOG_DEBUG
    ofstream debug_log("debug.log");
    #define log(...) debug_log << __FILE__ << ":" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "| " << __VA_ARGS__ << std::endl
#else
    #define log(...)
#endif

#endif
```

This header file is included in multiple c files. and using log() function. g++ is giving:

```
/tmp/ccMAjYSm.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `debug_log'
/tmp/ccHj3w7u.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/cc3LQ9GQ.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `debug_log'
/tmp/ccHj3w7u.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
```

Any clue?

Comment: @EugeneSh. How is that supposed to help exactly? He's defining an object at global scope multiple times (which is against ODR)

Comment: @Borgleader Right. The include guards have confused me at the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declared `LOG_DEBUG` at project-level (or in multiple translation units), they will all see the

```
ofstream debug_log("debug.log");
```

line and you'll have multiple definitions.

A possible solution: put it into a single translation unit while rendering all the others aware of its existence

Header

```
#ifndef _LOGGER_H_
#define _LOGGER_H_

#ifdef LOG_DEBUG
    extern ofstream debug_log;
    #define log(...) debug_log << __FILE__ << ":" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "| " << __VA_ARGS__ << std::endl
#else
    #define log(...)
#endif

#endif
```

A cpp file

```
ofstream debug_log("debug.log");
```

Answer (score 3):

Each source file that eventually `#include`s logger.h will see this:

```
ofstream debug_log("debug.log");
```

and so create that object. Now you have multiple objects named `debug_log`.

Forward declare the object here, but put the instantiation in a .cpp file.